# Looking for dataset of Audio with IPA transcription

Tags: dataset, ipa

I am currently conducting accuracy testing for the allosaurus project available at (https://github.com/xinjli/allosaurus). This project is designed to transcribe IPA data from audio files. My objective is to verify the accuracy of the transcription, particularly in handling of mispronunciations. While one approach would be to use a standard text transcription and convert it to IPA using other software, I am specifically interested in evaluating how well allosaurus handles mispronunciations in audio recordings.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find information on the training data utilized by allosaurus in their GitHub repository.